# Looking for good start for making my own controls in C# - VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Looking for good start for making my own controls in C# - VS2008

can i get some basic help for this ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Custom Controls in Visual C# .NET](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html)
- [Walkthrough: Authoring a User
  Control with Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(VS.71).aspx)
- [Creating Custom Controls With C#
  .Net](http://knol.google.com/k/creating-custom-controls-with-c-net#)
- [Writing your Custom Control: step by
  step](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cutebutton.aspx)
- [Tutorial 6: Creating and Using User
  Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx)